CORS pre-flight request issue when using API custom domain names
I have been stuck on this issue and it's driving me mad - for a bit of context, I'm trying to lodge a signin request from my front-end through my AWS API Gateway to a lambda function, which generates a session ID and passes back the cookies to the front-end. This was working well using my API invoke URL, although the cookies weren't being stored as my host URL (the invoke URL) was different to my domain (assume it's called test-domain.com) that I was hosting my website on. So, I created a custom API domain name (api.test-domain.com) and mapped my API through here. However, now that I've done this, it seems the request lodged from the front-end doesn't even reach my API now (Cloudwatch logs don't come through anymore with this API custom domain name). I've obtained the necessary certificates and believed I have everything set up correctly in Route 53 and Cloudfront, but below are some of the errors I'm getting on the front-end:
(console log)

Access to fetch at 'https://api.test-domain.com/Signin' from origin 'https://test-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

(issues)
Request Status  Preflight Request           Header                Problem      Invalid Value
Signin  blocked     Signin            Access-Control Allow-Origin   Missing Header

(Network Headers)

Request URL:
https://api.test-domain.com/Signin
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Remote Address:
65.8.134.40:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Length:
42
Content-Type:
application/json
Date:
Sun, 30 Jun 2024 03:38:24 GMT
Via:
1.1 17fbdb6773cc5e0c82beae07c5c66726.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Apigw-Id:
aKXvnF3MywMEJfg=
X-Amz-Cf-Id:
H1EU5-BIUGIT_v41h-Cd2bkYB-tRr85eV5CSV6MB1N7k8kXE0HI5xg==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop:
MEL50-C1
X-Amzn-Errortype:
MissingAuthenticationTokenException
X-Amzn-Requestid:
db150710-adf3-4fec-bc68-d141eb77b707
X-Cache:
Error from cloudfront
:authority:
api.test-domain.com
:method:
OPTIONS
:path:
/Signin
:scheme:
https
Accept:
/
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:
en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:
POST
Origin:
https://test-domain.com
Priority:
u=1, i
Referer:
https://test-domain.com/

I suspect it's something to do with my API mapping or the way Route 53 has been set up - I'll provide some details below:
domain certificate - test-domain.com (Global region) - In route 53 I have this pointed to my Cloudfront distribution that has my S3 bucket (test-domain.com which has my React.js build files) as an origin.
Api domain certificate - api.test-domain (Global region, but have also tried localising it to the region my API is in) - In route 53 I have this pointed to my custom API Gateway domain name. I also have my CNAME from when the certificate wad created. If i type this into my browser the page comes up, although tells me there is a missing authentication token (I can also see via whatsmydns.net this domain is active).
API settings:

Resource - Signin
Methods - OPTIONS,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin - https://test-domain.com
Credentials - true
Stage - Signin (deployed)

This is a small portion of my front end code that makes the request:
const response = await fetch('https://api.test-domain.com/Signin', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

I would be super appreciative if anybody could help me out!

You need to list Content-Type as an allowed request header in your CORS configuration.
